# Microsoft Shares, not sharing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, file-sharing, permissions

I have a machine called \shares\

There are two drives on it, the "Local Disk (C:)" and the drive I want to put the shared resources on "Shares (S:)"

[image]

This is a brand-new Server 2012, and I have a test folder located within the S: drive on which I have enabled sharing for Everyone, and also specifically for myself

[image]

This machine is on the correct domain, alone with the machine I am trying to share resources with.

Here's the weird issue: When I create a shared folder in the C: drive in this manner all shared machines can access it. When I create a folder in the S: drive, I get a permission denied error:

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the NTFS permissions
[image]

Comment: So it's telling you that you don't have permissions. What are the permissions? You did not tell us what the NTFS permissions where - only the share permissions. NTFS permissions take precedence over share permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question with a screen shot of the NTFS permissions. My user has full control.

Comment: Maybe better for SuperUser forums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the account you're using to connect to the share

1. Is an account that the server knows about (a domain account, or a local account with the same password on both systems), and
2. Has NTFS file permissions to read and write to the share, in addition to the permissions you set on the share itself.

Comment: Thanks Katherine,

I have verified these.

Comment: Can you view the share, but just not write?  (That's what it sounds like you're saying; just confirming.)

If so:  Try clicking advanced and propagating all permissions down across all child objects and see if that helps you.

Comment: When I navigate to \\shares\ I can see the Test2 folder that I want to access, but when I try to access I get the permissions error.

Comment: And you're definitely trying to access the share as domainname\adam?

Comment: Yup.

So when I click on Advanced and then Effective Access (to calculate my users effective access) all the check boxes are green, including "Full Control"

Comment: What does "creator/owner" say?

Comment: It says my domain account [Owner: Adam---(adam@---.---)]

Comment: I was actually asking if creator/owner had separate permissions on the share that were different from domainname\adam.

Comment: I see. Yes, when I look at the sharing itself it doesn't show my domain name, but my e-mail address (which is different). In other words, instead of saying Adam (adam@domain.net), it says Adam (adam@emailaddress.com). This is very strange, have you ever seen this happen before?

Comment: Hi Katherine. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. I solved it by removing/readding the machine to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Removed and readded to the domain. Seems to be working now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @slm Really? AdamF is the OP, and he has detailed what he's done to fix the problem.

Comment: @Bryan - as far as this answer goes no. Seems more like a comment, or the details of the solution should've been captured here in this answer.

Comment: @slm I don't see how you can really expand `removed and readded to the domain`. It's specific enough, any more text is pretty much superflous to any other professional or intern reading this.

Comment: @Bryan - I see what you're saying but as answers go it seems a little light, no? I did not downvote it or anything, just making a comment. Seems like all the crux of this answer is in the question along with the comments on the Q. Maybe reflect some of the comments in this answer?